# PL/SQL cursor returning duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

My cursor is returning each row twice and I can't figure out how to stop that.  Can anyone help?  Many thanks.

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE p_event_loc (Passed_variable in varchar) 
IS
  Cursor c1 is 
    select en, ln, pn
      from Et, Rn, Ln2, Pt
      where Rn.status = 1
        and Pt.pid = Rn.pid
        and Et.eid = Rn.eid
        and Ln2.lid = Et.lid;
  E_en Et.en%type;
  L_ln Ln2.ln%type;
  P_pn Pt.pn%type;
BEGIN
  Open c1;
  Loop
    fetch c1 into E_en, L_ln, P_pn;
    exit when c1%notfound; 
    dbms_output.put_line(Passed_variable|| ' is registered for ' || E_en 
      || ' at ' || L_ln);
  End loop;
  Close c1;
END;
```

Comment: Does query (you used in cursor declaration), when ran separately, also returns duplicates? If so, fix WHERE clause (if possible) or - as suggested by user*something* in their answer - apply DISTINCT to tle column list.

Comment: Please edit your question and supply test data which demonstrates the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duclipcates use `distinct` keyword after select:

```
 select distinct en, ln, pn
```